# Loading a 32-bit dll on a 64-bit server OS

Tags: .net, dll, 64-bit, 32-bit, visual-c++-installer

I am trying to use a third-party DLL that is on the 32-bit architecture. I understand that targeting my .NET executable to be 32-bit should help, but unfortunately that DLL has a dependency on "msvcr100.dll" (the C runtime). If i don't provide this dll i get a DllNotFound exception (which i am able to catch at runtime). However, if i also copy the msvcr100.dll with the 3rd party DLL i get the "<ExeName> has stopped working" crash message, and i can't really find out what's wrong.

Is there any way to deploy an official C runtime for 32-bit apps on a 64-bit server OS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the 32-bit version of the VC runtime on your 64-bit OS.

You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84).